# Does Gem ActiveAdmin protect against BruteForce Login,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I looked at the default configuration and schema produced for AdminUser,

```
create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end
```

There doesn't seem to be anything from stopping any hacker that knows an email to eventually get into the system. Is there any way I can use something like Devise, or some tutorial to protect myself from this?

Thanks

Comment: Think of it in terms of successive attempts.  A user should only be allowed so many login attempts from an IP before they're locked out.

Comment: I tried logging in many times with an incorrect password but existent email, and it didn't try to block me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Devise with ActiveAdmin, by adding the `devise` gem to your gemfile and changing your routes like this:

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

And then you can configure devise to lock a user after X tries

Model:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :lockable # ...
```

Devise config:

```
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]
config.unlock_strategy = :email
config.maximum_attempts = 20
```